# A river crossing puzzle with relatively prime problem

Tags: puzzle

I want to share a problem on a facebook group : https://www.facebook.com/groups/419858384791916/permalink/640398286071257/

99 people, numbered 2 to 100, are all on one side of a river and wish to reach the other side. There is a single boat with infinite capacity, but a group of people can only ride the boat together if every pair of people on the boat have numbers that are relatively prime.
How many back-and-forth trips are needed to transport every person across the river?

Comment: Hint: Think about how to transport the people with even numbers.

Comment: Query: does there have to be a person in the boat on every trip (i.e. return journey), or is there a captain who does that?

Comment: If there is no person that return in the boat, I think the solution is $49$. Why? See @Mark Bennet's hint. :)

Comment: @AlexSilva Note - if you think correctly about the problem you will see that there are a number of people who could act as "captain" and stay in the boat all the time until the last journey. I think we also need some clarity about what a "back-and-forth" trip is, because the crossings come in pairs until the last crossing (or the first crossing could be the spare one) - how do we count the spare.

Answer (score 2):

1. See, that $97$ (or any prime number greater than $50$) is relatively prime with all other numbers. Make number $97$ a captain - it can travel with any number.
2. See, that two even numbers can't travel together. There is then need for at least $50$ trips.
3. See, that for every even $2k\geq 2$, $2k$ and $2k+1$ are relatively prime.
4. For every even number $2k$ (except $96$ and $100$), $2k, 2k+1, 97$ travels to the other side, $97$ comes back - $48$ two way trips.
5. $96$ and $97$ travels to the other side, $97$ travels back - $1$ two-way trip
6. $100$ and $97$ travels to the other side - $1$ one-way trip

We have then $49$ two-ways trips and $1$ one-way trip.